# How to Declare Complex Nested C# Type for Web Service

Tags: web-services, asmx

I would like to create a service that accepts a complex nested type.  In a sample asmx file I created:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ServiceNest : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
   public class Block
   {
      [XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]
      public int number;
   }

   public class Cell
   {
      [XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]
      public Block block;
   }

   public class Head
   {
      [XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]
      public Cell cell;
   }

   public class Nest
   {
      public Head head;
   }

   [WebMethod]
   public void TakeNest(Nest nest)
   {
   }

}
```

When I view the asmx file in IE the test page shows the example SOAP post request as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <TakeNest xmlns="http://schemas.intellicorp.com/livecompare/">
      <nest>
        <head>
          <cell>
            <block xsi:nil="true" />
          </cell>
        </head>
      </nest>
    </TakeNest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It hasn't expanded the <block> into its number member.

Looking at the WSDL, the types all look good.  So is this just a limitation of the post demo page creator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But those elements **ARE** null. You need to construct them before they show up otherwise they are just null.

Comment: Do I have this right: the example POST XML isn't providing these elements and so indicates this with the xsi:nil="true" attribute?  I had expected the [XmlElement(IsNullable=false)] to inform consumers of the wsdl that nil elements weren't allowed.

Comment: You have the IsNullable on the int within the null block class so the int never has a chance to not be null.

Comment: I expected that marking all the members as IsNullable = false would tell the client that it wasn't allowed to pass a nil element.  At the end of the day the importers in .NET, Java and Ruby correctly read the nested structure.  I figure the .NET code that generates the example POST XML just gives up after a certain number of levels.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin pointed out the example POST XML indicates that those elements are nil.  I should have simply tried to consume the web service.  Once I did that I could see that the importer (either .NET, Java or Ruby) correctly created all the types.  So really there is no question here after all.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET code did not give up after a certain number of levels.

If you look at the code generated by "Add Web Reference", you'll find that there's a `bool numberSpecified` field. Only if the client sets that to `true` will the number be serialized.

If you look at the XML Schema, you'll see that the `number` element might be absent. If it were of a reference type, then that could be represented in the client by a `null` value. Since it's an `int`, this additional flag is necessary to indicate whether or not to serialize this optional value.